# Preconfigure filter, shown in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table, which shows two filters at once.

Here is my example:

[image]

As you can see, I am currently can only display one of the two results within a pivot table.

I tried to pre-align the filter in the filter tab and then move it down, however this only does work for one filter.

Any suggestion, how to "pre-configure" the column filter, so that I can get the desired row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this solution enough for you?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create the Pivot Table with Column Labels *Yes / No*, Row Labels *Category*, and for Values select the count of any field (e.g. Yes / No).